# How is it fair that kali yug is the only bad yug

Tags: belief, dharma, yuga

How is it fair that kali yuga  is the only bad yuga because Dwapara Yuga, Treta Yuga, and Satya yuga have most dharma while Kali yuga has the least dharma

Comment: Where did you read that it is a bad yuga?

Comment: @Wikash My mom told me that lot of people in this kali yuga are bad people

Comment: I did not read that

Comment: Technically speaking people will sin more and in that sense become bad but it is due to the demon Kali.

Comment: @Wikash_ Kali is not a demon. She is a powerful Shakti

Comment: That is a different Kali that is Kali devi. Kali is an asura which is the nemisis of the Kalki avatar.

Comment: okay @Wikash_ I never knew this

Comment: Wiki is not really a good source but in this case it can give some reliable info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_(demon)

Comment: what do you mean @Wikash_

Comment: You can read about the asura Kali there.

Comment: @Wikash_ Okay, I understand now

Comment: Kali (demon) and Kaali (devi) - are 2 different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said Kali Yug is bad ?

Ved Vyasa himself said "Kali Sadhu:" - meaning Kali is great

Each Yug has its own methods of attaining Bhagavan. Kali is the easiest.

[Vishnu Puran](http://gitabase.com/esp/SB/12/3/52):

> dhyayan krite yajan yajnais
>
> tretayam dvapare arcayan
>
> yad apnoti tad apnoti
>
> kalau sankirtya kesavam

Meaning:

> Whatever is achieved by dhyana in Satya-yuga,
>   by the performance of yagna in Treta-yuga,
>   and by puja in Dvapara-yuga,
>   that is obtained in Kali-yuga by glorifying Keshava.

So, in Kali, we don't have to do arduous penances because Bhagavan is very lenient - he knows that most people born in this Yug are spiritually weak and degraded and sinful, so he gave them an easy rope to climb out.

Comment: I assume you mean Srimad Bhagvatam instead of Vishnu Purana ?

Comment: What is the easy rope to climb out?

Comment: @Hanumanchailasa, chant Hanuman Chalisa :)

Comment: ha ha :)  I just got the name first so I put the name. I actually don't know  how to  say the whole stotram

Comment: There is no easy rope out: one can do charity, chant the name of god (be it Vishnu, Hanuman or whatever you like) and doing good deeds